# How to remove default cross icon from datetimefield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```dart
Center(
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent,width: 1),
      color: colorPrimary,
      borderRadius: radius(10),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.calendar_month,size: 20),
        Expanded(
          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                )
            ),
            child: DateTimeField(
              // readOnly: _isDateTimeReadonly,
              controller: _dobController,
              cursorColor: white,
              format: format,
              onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                if (_dobController.text.isEmpty) _selectedDate = "";
                // else if (!_isDateTimeReadonly)
                return showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                  // initialDate: _selectedDate!.isNotEmpty ? DateTime.parse(_selectedDate!) : DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now(),

                  // lastDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6570)),
                ).then((res) {
                  if (res != null) {
                    _selectedDate = res.toLocal().toString().split(' ')[0];
                    _dobController.text = _selectedDate!;
                    isDateSelected = true;
                    _affiliateReward.currentState!.refreshData();
                    print('Response Date : ${res}');
                    print('isDateSelected : ${isDateSelected}');
                  }
                  return res;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Icon(Icons.calendar_month,size: 20),

      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

So, above code is for datetimefield. I want to remove default cross icon. How do I remove it?

Comment: can you add a picture of it

Comment: You can use dialog for picking the date or time and for viewing purpose you can create your own custom view and then just show the picked value. This way you will be having a full control over the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `suffixIcon` and `suffix` property , and pass empty Container.

```
DateTimeFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Container(),
    // or
    suffix: Container(),
  ),
   // your other stuff
),
```